# How is the warning 'Source files should not have any duplicated blocks' suppressed in SonarQube?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am using SonarQube 5.4 and investigating the suppressing of several issues. I've found that SonarQube does not detect the suppression of the rule **Source files should not have any duplicated blocks** once I insert `@SuppressWarnings("common-java:DuplicatedBlocks")` in the beginning of the file (the file does not compile) or at the markup of the one of the duplicated code blocks.

I've found the information at http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+FAQ which states the following:

> The //NOSONAR tag is useful to deactivate all rules at a given line but is not suitable to deactivate all rules (or only a given rule) for all the lines of a method or a class. This is why support for @SuppressWarnings("all") has been added to SonarQube.

I am using the version 3.13.1 of SonarQube Java Plugin.

I am aware that I can mark the issue in the SonarQube GUI as a false positive but this will not transfer through branches which is a required feature for me.

How should I use the `@SuppressWarnings`-tag to disable the duplicated code block?

Comment: Shouldn't you really be spending the effort on reducing the duplication rather than hiding it?

Comment: Right now I am in a project to introduce the SonarQube tool to a company and I am introducing them to the tool. And sometimes the need to suppress these types of warnings are required, thus I am looking for the functionality if it exists and how it is constructed.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, makes sense then. From what I remember those suppressions can be a bit tricky. Generally if you can find the rule name you can do something like @SupressWarnings('RULE_NAME').

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a feature that is not supported : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-521

There is no plan to implement it for now but this might be addressed in the future.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way of suppressing specific issues in another way?

Comment: I am using SonarQube Community Edition Version 7.9.1 (build 27448). Is it not possible to ignore `common-java:DuplicatedBlocks` in this version also? I tried putting `@SuppressWarnings("common-java:DuplicatedBlocks")` at both method as well as class level and it did not work.