# How do I ignore duplicated code report in Sonar?

Tags: java, sonarqube

SonarQube reports as "block of duplicated code" to different simple POJO class like below.
In this case, A and B are different role. So, I think that I should not create abstract class.

```
public class A{
  private String xxx;

  // omitted other fields.

  public A() {}

  public String getXxx() {
     return xxx;
  }
  public void setXxx(String xxx) {
     this.xxx= xxx;
  }

  // omitted other fields' setter and getter

}

public class B{
  private String xxx;

  // omitted other fields.

  public B() {}

  public String getXxx() {
     return xxx;
  }
  public void setXxx(String xxx) {
     this.xxx= xxx;
  }

  // omitted other fields' setter and getter

}
```

The severity is major. So, I would like to ignore it. Then, I added `@SuppressWarning("common-java:DuplicatedBlocks")` and `@SuppressWarning("all")` to both classes. But it could not be ignored.

Though similar question was raised in [JIRA](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-521), but it have been not solved. My SonarQube's version is 6.5.

Comment: you can change the severity level to normal for this one

Comment: If the Xxxx fields genuinely **mean** the same thing, it *may* be appropriate to create an abstract superclass for `A` and `B`.  The fact that they are used differently doesn't imply that you can't or shouldn't extract common code. (Just saying ...)

Comment: @Yogen Rai Wow, I don't know it. Now my role is just a developer, I will ask to the administrator. Thank you!

Comment: @Neriudon  ya.. we always do that on each sprint if there is unnecessary severity level assignment :)

Comment: @Stephen C Certainly, I should consider to create create superclass to avoid this problem. Thanks!

Comment: At the time of asking this question, duplicate code was implemented as a Rule which you could resolve yourself. That's now been deprecated and replaced with a separate duplicate code metric which can't be resolved or have its severity reduced, so any older answers here are not going to be very useful.

Answer (score -14, accepted):

Putting this into the answer section to attach a screenshot:

If you are confident enough that those two blocks of code have different roles, then you can change the reported severity level to `Minor` or `Info` from web-console. For example, see the screenshot below:
[image]

Sometimes Sonar reports as severe on things which are not really severe, but again depends on the project nature :)

However, like @[Stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985/stephen-c) mentioned on a comment above, if `xxx` are same field and inheritance makes sense, then you can have parent abstract class to avoid the report.

Comment: But... in the case of "Duplicated Lines", Sonar is not showing an issue, so it is not possible to mark it as "won't fix"

Comment: hi @jmgonet Did u get any idea how to skip those duplicate line issue in sonar ?

Comment: This is incorrect, since Sonar doesn't show duplications as Issues as shown in the screen cap.

Comment: This is not the correct answer even though it is accepted. In case of code duplication, there is no way to mark it as Won't Fix.

Comment: Anyone figured out a way to mark it as won't fix? @jmgonet

Answer (score 36):

There are several ways for you to achieve this, depending on the importance you give to this duplication issue. SonarQube reports what it finds, it's all up to you to decide what to do with it.

- If you believe that this is indeed an issue, you have to refactor your code: SonarQube cannot report duplication when there is none
- If you believe that this particular instance is not an issue, you can either lower the severity of the issue, or mark it as "won't fix", with a nice comment for the person who will come after you - I believe that using `@SuppressWarnings` annotations for this is a bit of an abuse, when there are dedicated features in SonarQube
- If you believe that SonarQube should not even raise issues about duplicated code, you can either disable the rule (the nuclear option), or setup your analysis to ignore duplication for your POJO package(s)

For instance, you can add the following property to your scanner configuration:

```
sonar.cpd.exclusions=path/to/your/package/*.java
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. At first, I will try refactoring my code. Next, I will consider to change SonarQube configuration (not using `@SuppressWarnings`).

Comment: I am using autogenerated validation code which expands out the schemas of the objects it is validating. Any reused sub-objects will be definition be duplicates. It would be nice to just have an override in the UI for instances like this.

Comment: **or mark it as "won't fix"** - but how? I can't find this button for the report of duplicated lines. at all.

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to tweak the quality gate to suit your need. Need to keep in mind that default built-in quality gate is standard and should be always preferred.

Copy the default and create a new quality gate. Edit it to accept duplication percentage according to your comfort level (depending on your project needs).

[image: Copy the default and edit it to accept duplication percentage according to your comfort level]

Comment: not good enough, sometimes dup lines make sense in test suites, but nowhere else.   better to exclude them

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

However, if you find yourself in situations where ignoring certain issues, like duplicated code, is necessary (e.g., for temporary fixes or exceptions you know will be addressed later), there is a workaround:

You can temporarily disable the quality gate as a requirement for merging into the required branch. By doing this, you can bypass the warning and complete the merge.

For those using Azure DevOps:

- Navigate to Project Settings.
- Go to Repositories.
- Go to Policies.
- Under Branch Policies select Master (or the branch of your choice).
- Look for Status Checks.
- Adjust the settings as needed.

[image: Status Check Azure DevOps]

Answer (score -10):

Sonar helps us to improve code quality by applying certain rules.
But exceptions are always there and if you are confident that your code needs to suppress certain violation, you can use @SuppressWarnings.
eg @SuppressWarnings("common-java:DuplicatedBlocks")

Now how we will get reule info or id.

1. Go to sonar dashboard.
2. Click on Issues.
3. Select your class and issue and further check see rule.
4. Rule id is mentioned in the top right corner of rule description.

[image]

Comment: according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983618/how-is-the-warning-source-files-should-not-have-any-duplicated-blocks-suppress?rq=1 this does not work!