# sonarcloud dont check duplication javascript

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, sonarcloud

I've been looking for hours how to disable sonarcloud checking on duplicate lines/blocks in my `sonar-project.properties` file, and I still can't make it, it's driving me crazy.

I've tried
`sonar.cpd.exclusions=**/*.js`
`sonar.cpd.exclusions=**/*`

But it's not working.

How to achieve this simple task ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I ignore duplicated code report in Sonar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52865737/how-do-i-ignore-duplicated-code-report-in-sonar)

Comment: no it's not ! I don'tknow if it's because of JS but the `sonar.cpd.exclusions` is not working

Answer (score 0):

On Sonarqube server, It is written in General Settings > Analysis Scope that

> one asterisk `*` Matches zero or more characters and two asterisks `**` matches one or more directories

since you need to exclude all files in the project from duplication detection, I think the below pattern will do  the job

`sonar.cpd.exclusions=**/**`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it