# Sonar analysis how to get rid of "Too many duplication references" in jenkins pipeline log

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

A large portion of our code is based on a template, because of this sonar scanner falsely reports that code as having too many duplications.

I know it's only a warning, but it fills our Jenkins pipeline logs with warnings, we'll never fix, to the extent that real issues get overlooked.

Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/52869313/1817610 I added `sonar.cpd.exclusions=**/*.w`  to our scanner properties, but that does not eliminate the warnings.

The fragment of the log below shows 25 lines in the log for a single source, we have more than a thousand sources like that.

```
00:21:14  INFO: 3970/4255 - current file: X:/cce/build/develop/git/smartlisa/appl/src/erprap/fwkal-u.w
00:21:14  WARN: Too many duplication references on file src/erprap/fwkal-u.w for block at line 523. Keep only the first 100 references.
00:21:14  WARN: Too many duplication references on file src/erprap/fwkal-u.w for block at line 525. Keep only the first 100 references.
00:21:14  WARN: Too many duplication references on file src/erprap/fwkal-u.w for block at line 523. Keep only the first 100 references.
00:21:14  WARN: Too many duplication references on file src/erprap/fwkal-u.w for block at line 527. Keep only the first 100 references.
/// trimmed 20 similar lines
...
00:21:14  WARN: Too many duplication references on file src/erprap/fwkal-u.w for block at line 523. Keep only the first 100 references.
```

using SonarScanner 4.7.0.2747

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using the https://plugins.jenkins.io/log-file-filter/ plugin.

I added a filter to replace

```
.* WARN: Too many duplication references on file .*\n
```

with an empty string.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You had only to google for "WARN: Too many duplication references" to find: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/supress-ignore-warning-warn-too-many-duplication-references-on-file/27946 .

This tells you that you can't control that.

And to be frank, it isn't a "false" report.  I understand where you're coming from, as I used to work on a project where we generated a lot of our application code.  It's really not a good strategy.  You'd be better off with an architecture where common code is inherited or composed, not duplicated.

Comment: I think it is a false report because I excluded these files using sonar.cpd.exclusions=**/*.w .