# How to suppress duplicate code warning in php projects for Sonar Qube scans?

Tags: php, cakephp, annotations, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using the CakePHP framework for projects and all the migrations files follow the almost same line of code but the field name is different. now it is detected for duplicate lines for a few files.

I want tips to suppress or ignore duplicate line detection for specific files or methods by adding annotation in php files.

Is there any way to add some annotation or remark to ignore this check?

Comment: First result in google https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52865737/how-do-i-ignore-duplicated-code-report-in-sonar